# Custom Authentication in Google Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, slack

I have a question regarding authentication using Google Firebase.

For an app, I want to build an authentication similar to the one Slack uses: first, the user provides the input as to which group they want to log in to. If there exists a group with the same name as provided in the input, the user is then taken to a login/signup screen.

I've thought about storing users in the realtime database as follows, but I think there must be a better way to do this (since I don't think I can use the firebase authentication in this case):

```
groups: {
  "some_group_name": {
    "users": [
      "user1": {
        .. user 1 information
      },
      "user2": {
        .. user 2 information
      }
    ],
    "group_details": {
      "name": ..,
      "someGroupDetail": ..
    }
  },
  "some_other_group_name": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I haven't realized if there is an obvious answer yet, so I'm open to suggestions. How would you suggest I tackle this?

Thanks

PS: I'm building the application using Nativescript and Angular, and (so far) there is no server or database involved other than Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion that might work, is by using Firebase Auth Custom Claims. That way, you only need to store the group ID and group name in your realtime database, without worrying to keep changing the database each time user is added or removed.

This is one way you can do it:

1. Store database exactly like you have it, with it's group ID and name.
2. In your backend script (I recommend Cloud Function), each time a User is registering themselves, add custom claims in your user: Specifying what group is the User belong to.
3. Every time user authenticate, retrieve the group ID from custom claims. And there you get it!

*Note: be careful not to put too much information in your custom claims as it cannot exceed 1000 bytes.*

Read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: And a very awesome video that clearly explain it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to implement **Root-level collections**.

Which is to create collections at the root level of your database to organize disparate data sets(as shown in the image below).

[image: Root-level collections]

> **Advantages**: As your lists grow, the size of the parent document doesn't change. You also get full query capabilities on
>   subcollections.
>
> **Possible use case**: In the same chat app, for example, you
>   might create collections of users or messages within chat room
>   documents

Based on the reference from the firebase cloud firestore 
**[Choose a data structure tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)** (I know you are using Realtime database but structuring the database is the same since both are using the NoSQL Schema)

For your case:

1. Make 2 Collections: Users, Groups
2. Users: User info is stored in the form of document
3. Groups: In the Groups Collection, here comes the tricky part, you can either store all groups subcollection under 1 document or split into multiple documents (based on your preference)
4. In the group-subcollection, you can now store your group info as well as the user assigned where you can store user assigned in the form of array, therefore whenever a user access the group, query the user assigned first, if yes, then allow (assuming users can view all group)
5. You do the thinking now

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the root level collection structure seems reasonable. But I believe this way, I wouldn't be able to use the already existing authentication methods of Firebase, and I would thus have to deal with password hashing etc. Am I correct?

Comment: @saglamcem nope, you can use Firebase Auth and  once you detected its a new user (when the user sign up), create a method to store the info to the database, you can get info like UID, name and email from Firebase Auth